# How do I set up a mirroring session between iOS 8 and Yosemite?

Tags: macos, ios8, osx-yosemite

On OS X Yosemite, the screen of an iOS 8 device can be mirrored to the OS X machine and saved as a media file. This can be done manually using QuickTime Player, but I want to do the same programatically.

Reading the docs, the iOS 8 device should be exposed as a webcam.

Calling `[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]` on my Mac returns an `NSArray` with no elements.

How can I setup a mirroring session using iOS 8 and Yosemite? How can I detect the capture device for the mirroring session?

Comment: Did you ever find how to do that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quoting from p28 of [the PDF transcript for WWDC 2014 session #508 “Camera Capture: Manual Controls”](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/508xxfvaehrll14/508/508_camera_capture_manual_controls.pdf?dl=1):

> iOS devices are presented as CoreMedia IO “DAL” plug-ins
>
> You must opt in to see iOS screen devices in your OS X app
>
> ```c
> CMIOObjectPropertyAddress prop =
>                            { kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices,
>                              kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
>                              kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster };
> UInt32 allow = 1;
> CMIOObjectSetPropertyData( kCMIOObjectSystemObject,
>                            &prop, 0, NULL,
>                            sizeof(allow), &allow );
> ```

Also, see [my blog](https://nadavrub.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/macos-media-capture-using-coremediaio/) for CoreMediaIO capture sample to directly intercept the raw compressed payload sent out from the device

Comment: I can't get it to work properly. The iphone device is detected by [AVCaptureDevice devices] only when I start Quicktime and start new movie recording in it. Why this can happen?

Comment: It might take some time for the device to become ~mounted~/available, B4 setting the above install the proper NSNotification to get notified when a device is added, IMPORTANT NOTE: as of OS-X 10.10 iOS mirorring has a memory leak ( OS Bug ), long capture running sessions cause the huge memory leak