# Remote Access of iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, ios5, appium

I would like to  develop a remote monitoring application for iOS devices. For this I need  to communicate with iOS devices (iPhone/iPad) from Mac machine and get the screenshot from the device as well as send keystrokes or touch events to the device.

For example, I need to send following to the device to get capture the screen:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().captureScreenWithName("LoginScreen")
```

How should I send this command to the device and receive the screenshot? I need some pointers to communicate with the devices.

**My basic requirement is** - I have a iPhone application running. Now From client side (From remote machine through browser) we are controlling application. If I click on a login button then that operation should fired on on a device connected to Mac server. In this way we can fire events periodically.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the code in your example used UIAutomation test script from Apple. I think you should read some documents about it.

Here is a tutorial of UIAutomation and a link to Apple document.

http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html

Comment: I used these links but doesn't find anything helpful. My basic requirement is - I have a iPhone application running. Now From client side (From remote machine through browser) we are controlling application. If I click on a login button then that operation should fired on on a device connected to Mac server. In this way we can fire events periodically.

Comment: Take a look at calabash, you may find helpful info in order to send control to your iOS application. YOu have to import a calabash framework into your project. The website is: http://calaba.sh/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor a specific application U'll need to inject your RemoteControl SO ( or directly link it w/ the SO if U R the developer of the app ), re-sign the bundle with your dev profiles ( might req FairPlay removal on a separate Jail-Broken device ) and deploy it on your provisioned device.

If you want to monitor the device ( and not a specific app ), U'll need to:

1. For screen capture you can use the new iOS8/Yosmite USB Screen mirroring feature ( see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136429/how-do-i-set-up-a-mirroring-session-between-ios-8-and-yosemite/26814278#26814278) for details )
2. For remote control, using the linux [BlueZ](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluez.org%2F&ei=hylcVeaRM4PxUNP8gLAG&usg=AFQjCNEcWDYpFDSpT8qXeXncgAPk8dWQsw&sig2=IVgSihQOmlj-_WjkytP8uw) Bluetooth stack, you can simulate a HID keyboard ( see [this link](https://github.com/lkundrak/btkbdd/blob/master/btkbdd.pod) for details )
3. For a touch screen/mouse U'll need to Jail-break you device and install BTStack from cydia, OR, implement a HW Solution incorporating Apple Chips :(