# Recording an iOS device's screen from an OSX cocoa app with a lightning cable

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, avfoundation, quicktime

It's possible in Quicktime, with New Movie Recording > Camera dropdown > select iOS device. [AppShow](https://www.techsmith.com/techsmith-appshow.html) and [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/features.htm#record) both do it.

I've tried this

**Applescript**

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
set myrec to new movie recording
  tell myrec
      set current camera to video recording device named "Morten's iPod touch"
  end tell
end tell
```

But this gives me

> error "QuickTime Player got an error: Can’t set video recording device \"Morten's iPod touch\" of document \"Movie Recording\" to video recording device named \"Morten's iPod touch\" of document \"Movie Recording\"." number -10006 from video recording device "Morten's iPod touch" of document "Movie Recording"

**AVFoundation**
Since iOS devices appear as cameras in Quicktime, I figured it would be a capture device in AVFoundation, but this code

```
for device in AVCaptureDevice.devices() {
    println(device)
}
```

Just gives me my Facetime HD camera and a microphone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a mirroring session between iOS 8 and Yosemite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136429/how-do-i-set-up-a-mirroring-session-between-ios-8-and-yosemite)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must opt in to see iOS screen devices in your OS X app.

See "[How do I set up a mirroring session between iOS 8 and Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136429/how-do-i-set-up-a-mirroring-session-between-ios-8-and-yosemite)"

```
CMIOObjectPropertyAddress   prop    = {
    kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices,
    kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster
};
UInt32                      allow   = 1;

CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(kCMIOObjectSystemObject, &prop, 0, NULL, sizeof(allow), &allow);
```

You can get the list of devices using:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeMuxed];
```

Comment: Works! I wasn't able to translate this to Swift. Maybe it's not possible? (I wrote an objc class that only does the above, but bridging headers make Xcode autocompletion incredibly slow!)

Comment: Note: since iOS 17 (or macOS 13/14) you also need to add the "Camera" entitlement in order to receive any video frames.

Answer (score 3):

```
var property = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices), mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal), mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))
var allow : UInt32 = 1
let sizeOfAllow = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &property, 0, nil, UInt32(sizeOfAllow), &allow)
```