# Record iPhone/iPad screen from a OS X App just like QuickTime Player

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, quicktime, video-recording

I know it is possible to record iOS screen using QuickTime player. (iOS device appears as a camera)

Can I record the iOS screen using AVFoundation for Mac OS X?

I want to create an OS X app which can record iOS device screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit goes to [NadavRub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26814278/2648673)

Quoting from p28 of [the PDF transcript for WWDC 2014 session #508 “Camera Capture: Manual Controls”](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/508xxfvaehrll14/508/508_camera_capture_manual_controls.pdf?dl=1):

> iOS devices are presented as CoreMedia IO “DAL” plug-ins
>
> You must opt in to see iOS screen devices in your OS X app
>
> ```c
> CMIOObjectPropertyAddress prop =
>                            { kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices,
>                              kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
>                              kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster };
> UInt32 allow = 1;
> CMIOObjectSetPropertyData( kCMIOObjectSystemObject,
>                            &prop, 0, NULL,
>                            sizeof(allow), &allow );
> ```

Also, see [my blog](https://nadavrub.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/macos-media-capture-using-coremediaio/) for CoreMediaIO capture sample to directly intercept the raw compressed payload sent out from the device